# Multidimensional array in Arduino 2560

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, arduino

When I call the below function several times, something strange happens. Can someone help me please?

```
void fillCommandsArray( String commandName, String commandValue, String commandDelay ) {
  String commandsIndex[9] = { "j0", "j1", "j2", "j3", "g", "er", "ef", "el", "eb" };
  // Index of command name
  int index;
  // Finding the index of command name
  for( int i=0; i<9; i++ ) {
    if( commandName ==  commandsIndex[i] ) {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  // Fill the command name
  commands[index][0] = 1;
  // Fill the command value
  commands[index][1] = commandValue.toInt();
  // fill the command delay
  commands[index][2] = commandDelay.toInt();
}
```

The parameters are something like this:

```
fillCommandArray("er", "200", "2");
```

And `commands` array is something like this:

```
// Array for storing commands
int commands[9][3] = {
  { 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

When I call the function several times, the array will become like this every time:

first to fourth time:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 200 2000
0 0 0
1 200 2000
0 0 0
```

fifth time:

```
7 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 200 2000
0 0 0
1 200 2000
0 0 0
```

sixth time:

```
0 5 7
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 200 2000
0 0 0
1 200 2000
0 0 0
```

seventh time:

```
0 0 5
7 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 200 2000
0 0 0
1 200 2000
0 0 0
```

and go on...
The numbers 5 and 7 will shift automatically to the other indexes of the array.
I know `er` is the 5th index of `commandsIndex` and `el` is the 7th.
I just don't know how this is happening. Is this a hardware problem? Could this be a hardware problem?

Comment: What is the exact set of function calls you use that cause the problem?

Comment: Also how and where is `commands` defined?

Comment: As you know, in Arduino there are `setup()` and `loop()` functions. The former is called once and the latter is called in a loop. `commands` array is defined in the top of these two functions, where I have defined the other global variables, arrays and constants. There is one function which is called that cause calling `fillCommandsArray()`.

Comment: And that function is called in the `loop()` after receiving new Serial Data which is a valid command.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code we can't help. I don't see anything wrong with your function here except that you don't check for the commandName not being found.